# Returning List of Object from Repository by avoiding creation of entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

In Spring boot, here is the repository class

```
class DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoEntity, String>{

@Query(nativeQuery = true,value="SELECT t1.*, t2.DEMO2_NAME FROM DEMO1 as t1 LEFT JOIN DEMO2 as t2   ON t1.ID = t2.ID")
**List<DemoEntity> get();**

}
```

Here a DemoEntity is needed with columns as

1. all 50 columns of table 1 (DEMO1)
2. DEMO2_NAME of table 2 (DEMO2)

**Since DEMO1 table can have 50 columns. It is difficult to put all 50 column names in entity.
So, How to avoid creating entity class and return List of Objects instead of List of Entity?**

Comment: And how would an object hold those 50 columns.

Comment: I don't think you can do this as far as I know. Say even if you manage to take a list of Objects at some point you will need to access those data right?

Comment: What is difficult about putting "all 50 column names in entity"?